# Python dataframe changing number format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I want to change number format from 7051252.94 to 7 051 252.94 etc
I tried:
 replace and format({'Revenue': '{: .2f}'}), neither of which worked

**My Code**

```
df['Revenue'] = df['card_price'] * df['buyers']
df_revenue_top5_bottom5 = df[['card_manufacturer','Revenue']].groupby('card_manufacturer',as_index=False).sum().sort_values(by=["Revenue"], ascending = False)

df_revenue_top5_bottom5 = df_revenue_top5_bottom5.head(5)
df_revenue_top5_bottom5.style.bar(color='lightgreen').format({'Revenue': '{:.2f}'})
```

**Result**

```
    card_manufacturer   Revenue
9   Gigabyte    14479296.76
15  MSI 7051252.94
5   Asus    5818987.93
20  Palit   4745429.54
22  Sapphire    4024812.98
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `precision`/`thousands` [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) while setting the revenue as a `subset` :

```
(
    df_revenue_top5_bottom5.style.bar(color="lightgreen")
        .format(thousands=" ", precision=2, subset="Revenue")
)
```

Preview :

[image]